# Wordpress get the data and push into array

Tags: foreach, wordpress

I want to get the data from WordPress DB, pushed them into array and past the data to JS.

Got it all working except pushing the data into array in `foreach ($posts as $post)`.

Full method:

```
        $array = array(); 
        $category_name = "locations";
        $args = array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'category_name' => $category_name
        );

        $posts = get_posts($args);      
        foreach ($posts as $post){
            array_push( $array, array(

                "title" => the_title($post->ID),
                "cnt" => the_content($post->ID),
                "id" => the_ID($post->ID),
                "link" => the_permalink($post->ID)

            )); 
        }
```

When I do `print_r($array)` i get a following mix:

```
Post 39http://localhost:8080/testing/post-3/Post 27http://localhost:8080/testing/post-2/Post 15http://localhost:8080/testing/post-1/Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => 
            [cnt] => 
            [id] => 
            [link] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => 
            [cnt] => 
            [id] => 
            [link] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => 
            [cnt] => 
            [id] => 
            [link] => 
        )

)
```

**What is going on? Why is the data not placed correctly into the array?**
Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those template tags need to have their echo variable set to false to work in that context. They also don't take post ID as a variable, they assume the current post if postdata is setup. Try:

```
the_title('','',false)
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title

---

### -~ -~ -~ -~ -~ -~ -~ -~ CLARIFICATION EDIT -~ -~ -~ -~ -~ -~ -~ -~

The tidiest solution to this problem was actually to directly address the wp `$post` object. So for the title string `$post->post_title` and for the content `$post->post_content`

The fields available in the `$post` object are listed here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post#Return

Comment: `the_title('','',false)` works! Is there a alternative for the rest of the standard data (content, id, permalink etc..) as well?

Comment: For the data you need it would actually be better to use `get_the_title($postid)` and so on as Dan suggests. For example the_content() doesn't have an echo false option.

Comment: Just had a look at get_the_content() and yea it doesn't return a string either. Your best bet will get to get the whole post as an array and take the values from that. Use [get_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post)

Comment: lol actually scrap that. As you've already done a get_posts I think the post is already set up as an object. Try `$post->post_content`, I believe that will give you the content as a string. Use the get_posts codex page link from before to see the names of the other values you want.

Comment: $post->post_content does work! Thanks! Any idea how would this work with custom meta boxes??

Comment: with custom meta values? not sure if that is in the $post object, might be. Best to `var_dump($post)` to find out what is in there. If not just `get_post_custom($post->ID)` into an array and pull out the values.

Answer (score 1):

These functions (the_title, the_content, etc) do not return values, they `echo` them to output. They also don't take an ID argument. You need to use `get_the_title`, `get_the_content`, etc., the versions that return a string.

Comment: `get_the_title` works. Unfortunately get_the_content returns empty (yes, there is some content). Any idea? Thanks!